# How to Deploy ApK to Phone (Visual Studio 2019 + Xamarin Forms)

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have basically made a default Xamarin Forms App in VS 2019 and I would like to deploy it to my Samsung A52 but I am not sure how.

I clocked on the .Andriod file and did Archive that makes an apk but when I put it on my phone I get

"There was a problem while parsing the package"

I don't know if I need to get it "signed" first or what. I have installed a custom apk before (my own that I made many many years ago) so I should be able to install custom apks.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/debugging/debug-on-device?tabs=macos

Comment: Hi, can you create an emulator then install the apk on the emulator and check if it shows the same problem?